# (custom user) createsuperuser TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I've created a new Django project and the first thing I did was create a custom user with the help of Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/

After I wrote all the code for a custom user, and after I did **makemigrations** and **migrate** for the first time in this Django project, I tried to create a superuser while my virtual env is active by writing:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

But it gave me this error:

> TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string

I wrote all the custom user code in an app called **accounts**.

In the **settings** file I added 'accounts' to the INSTALLED_APPS list, and added in the bottom this line:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

Here's all my source code, starting with models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


    def create_staffuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name):

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Staff and superusers must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Staff and superusers must have a last name")

        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password
        )

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name):

        user = self.create_staffuser(
            email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email               = models.EmailField(null=True, max_length=80, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD      = 'email'
    is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name          = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name           = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined         = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS     = [first_name, last_name]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name():
        return first_name

    def get_full_name():
        return first_name + ' ' + last_name
```

Then I wrote this in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import CustomUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
     """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
password hash display field.
"""
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

And in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser
from .forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Meta', {'fields': ('date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_active',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name' 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

This is the entire error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/howdidthishappen/Projects/project-root/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/howdidthishappen/Projects/project-root/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/howdidthishappen/Projects/project-root/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 282, in run_from_argv
    options = parser.parse_args(argv[2:])
  File "/home/howdidthishappen/Projects/project-root/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 54, in parse_args
    return super().parse_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1739, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1760, in parse_known_args
    if not hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS     = [first_name, last_name]
```

It should be:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS     = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

That's why I had a TypeError saying "attribute name must be a string".